# how to write junit test cases for this method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.6 RELEASE and JUnit 4.11. In a particular Spring controller, I have a method that ends thusly.....

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/chipset/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addChipSet(@ModelAttribute("chipset") Chipset c){
    this.chipsetService.addChipset(c);
    return "redirect:/chipset";
}
```

In my JUnit test, how do I verify return from a submission to my controller in which this Redirect is returned? I used to use

```
@Test
public void addChipsetTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/chipset/add"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(redirectedUrl("chipset/redirect"));
}
```

but this is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`

so please do help me

Comment: Can you show the set up of your mockMvc and where exactly is the null pointer being thrown?

Comment: here is the setup of mockMvc                                                                private MockMvc mockMvc;       and NullPointerException is throwing here        
               mockMvc.perform(post("/chipset/add"))

Answer (score 0):

You dont pass the Chipset c argument in your post test request,
I think it's `this.chipsetService.addChipset(c);` which throw a nullPointerException.

Comment: i wrote like this , now it's working fine                        

@Test
 public void addChipsetTest() throws Exception {
  Chipset chipset=getChipSetEntity();
  objectUnderTest.addChipSet(chipset);
  
  
  }

Comment: but it's not a functional test. now it's a unit test